# how to setup an alias apache2

Tags: 12.04, apache2, alias

I am new to UBUNTU and try to use apache to check a website that I am currently developing using Joomla (novice to that too).  I am trying to setup an alias in httpd.conf, but have not been successful.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not mix xamp with lamp. lamp is official. xamp is a project someone should not have started ;)

Answer (score 9):

I would expect an alias to be included in the virtual host you created in `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/`.

Example:

```
VirtualHost *> 
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website

    Alias /website "/var/www/html/website"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/website">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial from digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: This answer leads to a deprecated article.